# why is my code printing error when I input user data in postman?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was creating an eCommerce app in node.js and tried a post request to postman to accept a new user details for registration but it keeps printing the error message rather than the data.

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email})

.exec((error, user) => {


    if (user) return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'User already registered'
    });

    const{
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password
    } = req.body;
    const _user = new User({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password,
        username: Math.random().toString()
    });

   _user.save((error, data) =>{
    if (error){
        //console.log(data)
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Something went wrong'
        });
    }
    if(data){
        return res.status(201).json({
          message: 'User Created Successfully..!'  
        })
    }
   });
```

[image]

Comment: You used `if (error)` so what's the error?

Comment: Because `_user.save()` returned an error. Which one? nobody knows ... You could for instance include the `error` in your response ...